# How to get data of that line and before that line and after that line in python

Tags: python, file

I have a file example.txt which contains the following data in it
**example.txt:**

```
Email & Password: hifza
name: abc
Country: US


Email & Password: trfff
name: abc
Country: US

Email & Password: trfff
name: xyz
Country: US

Email & Password: trfff
name: ttt
Country: US
```

I want to store data in three diffrent files.If name is abc email,name and country should be stored in abc.txt file.If name is xyz all the data of xyz should be placed in xyz.txt.
This is my code It is only saving data for name line.But i want email and country also.

```
with open("example.txt") as f:
   with open("abc.txt", "w") as f1:
      for line in f:
        if "abc" in line:
            f1.write(line) 
        elif "xyz" in line:
            with open("xyz.txt", "w") as f2:
                f2.write(line)  
        elif "ttt" in line:
            with open("ttt.txt", "w") as f3:
                f3.write(line)
```

Comment: but how i can get before that line and after that line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant solution but it works:

```
with open('fil') as f_in:
    with open('abc.txt', 'w') as abc, \
            open('xyz.txt', 'w') as xyz, \
            open('ttt.txt', 'w') as ttt:
        lines = f_in.read().split('\n\n')

        for line in lines:
            if 'name: abc' in line: out = abc
            elif 'name: xyz' in line: out = xyz
            elif 'name: ttt' in line: out = ttt
            else: out = None
            if out:
                out.write(line.strip() + '\n')
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as infile:

    line = infile.read().split("\n\n")
    for l in line:
        l = l.strip() // get rid spaces and empty lines
        l = l.split("\n")
        filename = l[1].split(":")[1].strip() + ".txt"
        with open(filename, "w+") as outfile:
            for i in l:
                outfile.write(i + "\n")
```

Comment: You should either use:
`with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:` or add an `outfile.close()` at the end to make sure the file is closed.

Comment: @JanZeiseweis thank you for notifying me. Will edit my answer.

Comment: I am a beginer can you please edit this in my code?or explain this?

Comment: I made some changes to your code. I hope you don't mind. First strip the empty lines and spaces and also open the file to write in 'w+' which appends to existing files instead of overwriting them.

Comment: @Hifzaahmad We start by reading all the file and assigning to `line` and getting a list of entries by separating the line every two consecutive newline characters `\n`. Then for every element (entry) of that list, we split it again based on `\n` to get all fields(email, name, country) and we access the second field, which is the name, splitting it again based on : character and getting the second element of that split result, which is the actual name needed for filename. About using `split`, see https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.split.